# Query to Search for DOM a Specific DOM element

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io

In the DOM below, how can I search for the element that has "Subtotal" as innerText, and get the next/sibling element to get the actual value?
In the Chrome console, I was able to do `$$('tbody[class="MuiTableBody-root"]')[5].children[0].children[1]`

I am specifically seeking the query to search for "Subtotal" and get the sibling.

```
<tbody class="MuiTableBody-root">
   <tr class="MuiTableRow-root">
      <td class="MuiTableCell-root jss93 MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-alignRight">Subtotal</td>
      <td class="MuiTableCell-root jss93 MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-alignRight">$0.00</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="MuiTableRow-root">
      <td class="MuiTableCell-root jss93 MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-alignRight">Total</td>
      <td class="MuiTableCell-root jss93 MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-alignRight">$0.00</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="MuiTableRow-root">
      <td class="MuiTableCell-root jss93 MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-alignRight">Total Price/Unit</td>
      <td class="MuiTableCell-root jss93 MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-alignRight">$0.00</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work for you ?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(() => {

  var $tds = jQuery("td").each(function(){
    if(this.innerText.trim().toLowerCase() == "subtotal"){
      console.log(this.innerText);
      let $adjacent = $(this).next();
      let amount = $adjacent.text().trim();
      console.log(amount);
    }
    
  });


})
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


</html>

<body>

  <table class="MuiTableBody-root">

    <tr class="MuiTableRow-root">
      <td class="MuiTableCell-root jss93 MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-alignRight">Subtotal</td>
      <td class="MuiTableCell-root jss93 MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-alignRight">$0.00</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="MuiTableRow-root">
      <td class="MuiTableCell-root jss93 MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-alignRight">Total</td>
      <td class="MuiTableCell-root jss93 MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-alignRight">$0.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="MuiTableRow-root">
      <td class="MuiTableCell-root jss93 MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-alignRight">Total Price/Unit</td>
      <td class="MuiTableCell-root jss93 MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-alignRight">$0.00</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  
</body>
```

Comment: This does work. What would be the jquery that I can use in the Chrome console just to get the Subtotal?

Comment: avoid the document ready block: var $tds = jQuery("td").each(function(){
    if(this.innerText.trim().toLowerCase() == "subtotal"){
      console.log(this.innerText);
      let $adjacent = $(this).next();
      let ammount = $adjacent.text().trim();
      console.log(ammount);
    }
    
  });

Comment: Why can we not use find(e=>e.innerText === 'Subtotal') ?